# Precedence constrainted biknapsack

Tags: c++, optimization, cplex

I don't have a stong background in combinatorial optimization nor programming and I have to write some code to solve the bi knapsack (2 capacities ) with constraints of precedence.. I've been working on it for 3 months now and I can't debug it and find out why it doesn't return the right answers yet ... I used a CONCERT configuration on C++

So here's how my program works :

First I solve the linear relaxation using CPLEX, the output returns the value of the objective function + the index of the fractional variable + a variable that indicates if the relaxation is feasible + a variable that indicates if all variables are integer .

Second I implemented a branch and bound function that does a BFS tree search

so first it verifies if the relaxation is feasible and then if it is and there are fractional variables it branches on them ..

each node has 2 caracteristics : its bound which means the value of the relaxation in this node + a list of values indicating if the decision was taken on a variable or not ( it is equal to 0 if we decide not to pick the element , 1 if we decide to pick it, and 2 if we have not yet taken any decision ...)

So here's my code , problem is it branches ONLY on the first node

```
#include <queue>
#include<cmath>
#include<ilcplex/ilocplex.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<typeinfo>
using namespace std;

IloEnv env;
IloCplex cplex;
IloModel model;


struct node
{
    double bound;
    int val[100];
    int profit;

};


/***************************BORNE***************************/


double *bound(node u,int T,int W,int n,int Pre[],int CapaciteTemps[],int CapaciteSac[],int CoutObj[]){

    int indicefrac=0;
    double *resultat=new double[4];

    try{
        env = IloEnv();
        model=IloModel(env);


        //définition des variables de décision
        IloNumVarArray x(env,n);
        for (IloInt i=0; i<n;i++){
            x[i]=IloNumVar(env);
        }


        //contrainte 1: Capacité temps
        IloExpr Contr1(env);
        for (IloInt i=0; i<n;i++){

            Contr1 += CapaciteTemps[i]*x[i];

        }

        model.add(Contr1<=T);



        //contrainte 2: Capacité volume
        IloExpr Contr2(env);
        for (IloInt i=0; i<n;i++){

            Contr2 += CapaciteSac[i]*x[i];
        }
        model.add(Contr2<=W);


        //contrainte 3: Relaxation des variables entre 0 et 1 les variables peuvent prendre des valeurs continues mais que sur l'intervalle 0,1

        for (IloInt i=0; i<n;i++){
            model.add(0<=x[i]<=1);
        }


        //contrainte 4: Contrainte de précédence si l'on veut prendre un élément il faut avoir nécéssairement avoir pris tout ses prédécesseurs

/*
        for(IloInt i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(IloInt j=0;j<n;j++){

                if(Pre[i]<=Pre[j])

                {
                    model.add(x[i]>=x[j]);
                }

            }
        }



*/

        //élément pris ou non on force sa valeur a être égale à 0 ou à 1

        for (IloInt i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(u.val[i]==0){
                model.add(x[i]<=0);}
            else if(u.val[i]==1){
                model.add(x[i]>=1);
            }


        }

        //fonction objectif
        IloExpr obj(env);
        for (IloInt i=0;i<n;i++){
            obj += CoutObj[i]*x[i];
        }
        model.add(IloMaximize(env,obj));

        cplex=IloCplex(model);

        cplex.solve();


        //affichage de la valeur des variables



        for(IloInt i=0; i<n; i++){
            cout<<"x["<<i<<"]= "<<cplex.getValue(x[i])<<endl;
        }

        if ( ! (cplex.getStatus() == IloAlgorithm::Infeasible ) ) {
            bool isfractionnelb=false;
            double isfractionneli;

            for(IloInt i=1;i<n;i++){

                if(cplex.getValue(x[i]) != (int)cplex.getValue(x[i]))
                    isfractionnelb=true;
            }


            if(isfractionnelb==true){
                for(IloInt i=1;i<n;i++){


                    if(abs(cplex.getValue(x[i])-0.5)<abs(cplex.getValue(x[indicefrac])-0.5) ){
                        indicefrac=i;
                    }
                }
            }


            if(isfractionnelb==true)
            {isfractionneli=1;}
            else{isfractionneli=0;}



            resultat[0]=cplex.getObjValue(); // borne , valeur de la relaxation
            resultat[1]=(double)indicefrac;  //indice fractionnaire
            resultat[2]=isfractionneli; // indique si une valeur fractionnaire existe après la relaxation
            resultat[3]=1;  // indique si la relaxation linéaire est réalisable


        }
        if (  (cplex.getStatus() == IloAlgorithm::Infeasible ) ){cout<<"infeasable";}



    }catch(IloException& e){


        e.print(cout);


    }


    return resultat;

}




int knapsack(int n, int p[],int t[],int T,int w[], int W, int Pre[])
{
    queue<node> Q;
    node v,ug,ud;
    vector<int> pV;
    vector<int> wV;
    vector<int> tV;
    vector<int> tPre;
    Q.empty();

    double *borneg;
    double *borned;



    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        pV.push_back(p[i]);
        wV.push_back(w[i]);
        tV.push_back(t[i]);
        tPre.push_back(Pre[i]);
    }

v.profit=0;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {v.val[i]=2;}

    int maxProfit = 0;

    double *borne=bound(v,T, W, n,Pre, t, w, p) ;
    v.bound=borne[0];
    cout<<"borne "<<borne[0]<<endl;


    if(borne[2]==1){
        cout<<"indice fractionnaire : "<<borne[1]<<endl;}
    Q.push(v); // adds at top of list


    if( borne[3]==1 ){
        if(borne[2]==0){
            cout<<"la solution optimale est : "<<endl;
            maxProfit=borne[0];
            v = Q.front(); // reference a l'élement suivant dans la liste
            Q.pop(); // supprime l'élément suivant de la liste
        }

        else{
            // v = Q.front(); // reference a l'élement suivant dans la liste
            // Q.pop(); // supprime l'élément suivant de la liste
            //Q.push(v); // adds at top of list

            while (!Q.empty())
            {

                v = Q.front(); // reference a l'élement suivant dans la liste
                Q.pop(); // supprime l'élément suivant de la liste

                cout << "Noeud courant:";
                for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i)
                    cout << " " << v.val[i];
                cout << endl;
                cout << "Objet fractionnaire: " << borne[1] << endl;


                int indice=(int)(borne[1]);

                node ug;
                node ud;
                int k[n];

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
if (ud.val[i]==0)
k[i]=0;
else if (ud.val[i]==1)
k[i]=1;
else
k[i]=0;
}

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{ud.profit+=p[i]*k[i];}
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    int k[n];
if (ug.val[i]==0)
k[i]=0;
else if (ug.val[i]==1)
k[i]=1;
else
k[i]=0;

}

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{ug.profit+=p[i]*k[i];}

                for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                {ug.val[i]=v.val[i];
                ug.val[indice]=1;
                }


                for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                {ud.val[i]=v.val[i];}
                ud.val[indice]=0;


                borneg=bound(ug,T, W, n,Pre, t, w, p) ;
                borned=bound(ud,T, W, n,Pre, t, w, p) ;



cout<<"borne fils gauche"<<borneg[0]<<endl;
cout<<"borne fils droite"<<borned[0]<<endl;


                if(borned[3]==1)
                {if (borned[2]==0){
if(ud.profit>maxProfit)
{maxProfit=ud.profit;}
                    if (borned[0]>maxProfit)
                    {

                     borne[1]=borned[1];
            //  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                        //      {v.val[i]=fil[1].val[i];}
                         //     v.bound=fil[1].bound;
Q.push(ud);
                    }

                }

                }

            //  else {ud = Q.front(); // reference a l'élement suivant dans la liste
            //  Q.pop();
            //  cout<<"aaaaa";}


                if(borneg[3]==1)
                {if (borneg[2]==0){
                    if(ug.profit>maxProfit)
                    {maxProfit=ug.profit;}

                    if (borneg[0]>maxProfit)
                    {Q.push(ug);
                    borne[1]=borneg[1];

            //      for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            //      {v.val[i]=fil[0].val[i];}
             //     v.bound=fil[0].bound;
               //   borne[1]=borneg[1];
                    }
                }

                }

                //else {
                //ug = Q.front(); // reference a l'élement suivant dans la liste
                //Q.pop();
                //}

cout<<"debug1"<<endl;


            }
            cplex.exportModel("/net/cremi/sbounejmate/prog1.lp");

        }}
    else{cout <<"problème irréalisable"<<endl;
    maxProfit =0;

    }

    return maxProfit;
}

int main()
{

    vector<int> pV;
    vector<int> wV;
    vector<int> tV;
    vector<int> tPre;
    int n = 6;
    int W = 6;
    int T= 3;
    int p[6]= {15,5,15,15,3,5};
    int w[6]= {1,5,5,10,2,3};
    int t[6]={2,1,3,2,2,3};
    int Pre[6]={1,1,5,1,18,1};
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        pV.push_back(p[i]);
        wV.push_back(w[i]);
        tV.push_back(t[i]);
    }

    //double *b=bound(u,T, W, n, t, w, p) ;
    int k=knapsack(n,p,t,T,w,W,Pre);
    cout<<"knapsack"<<k<<endl;

    //cout<<"La valeur de la relaxation de l'objectif est : "<<b[0]<<endl;
    //cout<<"L'indice fractionnaire le plus proche de 0.5 est : "<<b[1]<<endl;


    return 0;


}
```

I'd be very grateful if you help me find out where my logic went wrong

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to solve your problem, but if you're working three months on this, then you need some strategies.

I'm missing any kind of debugging information. It's easy. You add some variables

```
static bool debug_thisthing = true;
static bool debug_thatthing = true;
... and so on
```

and then for example afer the code following "définition des variables de décision" you add

```
if (debug_thisthing) {
    ... print out stuff to make sure that you can check 
    ... that these values are correct. 
}
```

And you do that with after every step, making sure that at every step you have the results that you expect, and once you've checked one bit you can set the debugging code for that part to false.

One day of focused work and you'll be in a much better position.

Next you construct some examples where you can find the solution by hand, and see how they work out.

Comment: Hey @gnasher729 , well thank you so much, it's not the code that isn't working but the bfs strategy, the code compiles correctly but the bfs tree search is not done at all and I've been looking for so long and I can't figure out why..

Comment: So what actually happens? As gnasher729 says, get more debugging and logging in place and then try with a really simple problem instance and follow what happens and check it step-by-step with your intention. As I keep telling people, there is nothing special about optimisation software - it is just software and you resolve these issues using the same tools and techniques as any other programming problem.